# Tensorflow on Raspberry Pi 3 (Android Things vs Raspbian)

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, android, android-things

I want to create a **tensorflow** based detection system in an **IOT** setup. Will it perform better if I run it on **Android Things** or **Raspbian**? I expect to be using Full Yolo or tiny Yolo running on tensorflow. I am using Raspberry Pi 3.

Also please suggest any other OS if it is better than these two.

Comment: On Android Things you'd be limited to TensorFlow lite/mobile (unclear on the distinction), I'm not sure if this limitation would be the same on Raspbian, which could hypothetically run the full version. Depends whether this is a pro or con in your eyes.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a relatively old question (1 year) but I came across a similar issue so here is what I did.

```
Will it perform better if I run it on Android Things or Raspbian?
```

I would go for **Raspbian**, since this is [officially supported](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_raspbian) by Tensorflow.

**Note:** Raspberry Pi device must be running Raspbian 9.0 or higher

Make sure you have Python 2.7 or Python3.4+ installed on your system, as well as `pip` or `pip3`. If not, you can follow the instructions to install Python [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/Download), and pip [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_(package_manager)).

You can follow the TensorFlow [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_raspbian) for a proper installation.